# How to control pop up that embeds a payment system?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, zoho

I am came across to a situation where I need to use a adf popup to put a payment system on it from zoho subscriptions. The way we developed it, when user agrees such some condition they will get a pop up where the zoho subscription payment shows up. Everything was working as expected but when user confirm payment the embedded zoho payment system triggers thank you page after showing the payment successful from the popup. We cannot use javascript that's is requirements. We need to close the popup when payment successful. Can any one put some idea which direction we should go to achieve this solution?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the API that ZOHO provides to conduct the payment through your code instead of relying on their UI.
This will allow you to control the full UI experience from ADF.
ADF should be able to access the API easily.
https://www.zoho.com/invoice/api/v3